# Verify Signature XADES throw java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, xml-signature, xades4j

I need to verify signature XADES in signed xml file. I use xades4j v. 1.4.0 but when call method verify throw java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0.
With some file work , with other one no.

I have tried in debug mode and the exception throw in method checkForm  -XAdESFormChecker class.

My code:

```
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(inputStream);
                DOMHelper.useIdAsXmlId(doc.getDocumentElement());                    
                NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ds:Signature");
                Element elem = null;                      
                for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        elem = (Element) nNode;
                        elem.setIdAttributeNS(null, "Id", true);
                    }
                }
                data = item.getData();               
                CertificateValidationProvider certValidator = new CertificateValidationProviderImpl();
                XadesVerificationProfile p = new XadesVerificationProfile(certValidator);
                XadesVerifier v = p.newVerifier();
                SignatureSpecificVerificationOptions opts = new SignatureSpecificVerificationOptions().useDataForAnonymousReference(data);   
                XAdESVerificationResult result = v.verify(elem, opts);
```

The signature :[Xml signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVoci.png)

Can you help me? 
What is the error?

---

### EDIT - STACK TRACE

*java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at xades4j.verification.XAdESFormChecker$XAdESFormDesc.getPrevious(XAdESFormChecker.java:109)
    at xades4j.verification.XAdESFormChecker.checkForm(XAdESFormChecker.java:55)
    at xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.verify(XadesVerifierImpl.java:213)
    at it.yyy.kkkFramework.albo.InserimentoRichiestaController.listenerUploadDoc(InserimentoRichiestaController.java:1811)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:187)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at org.richfaces.event.MethodExpressionEventListener.processEvent(MethodExpressionEventListener.java:125)
    at org.richfaces.view.facelets.FileUploadHandler$FileUploadListenerImpl.processFileUpload(FileUploadHandler.java:55)
...

Comment: You should add the stacktrace, to make it easier for others to help.

Comment: @BerndBöllert  I paste stack trace, thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: @lgoncalves can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xades4j is based in ETSI TS 101 903 (XAdES 1.4.1). You signature, however, contains *SigningCertificateV2*, which is a property defined in more recent XAdES specs, not yet supported by xades4j. This is causing the error, as the *SigningCertificate* property is not present.

The library shouldn't be throwing the "array out of bounds" exception (this will be fixed, as it is a bug), but it wouldn't be able to verify the signature. If it wasn't for the bug you'd see the much more obvious exception thrown in this line: https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/blob/master/src/main/java/xades4j/verification/XAdESFormChecker.java#L64

Comment: Thanks, how can I then verify in java this signature?

Comment: For now, only using a different library. I believe there are others; maybe some support the updated standards